# How do I specify which reference table my function should look up?

Tags: r

I am building a nutrition score calculator. As a simplified example, the calculator takes a food's (1) amount of fibre and (2) food category as input and outputs a score of the product's healthiness based on its fibre content.

However, the scoring of fibre is adjusted depending on which food category the product is in. For example, in the below code a Category A product with fibre value of 1 should score 3 points, but a Category B product with fibre value of 1 should score 6 points.

```
library(tidyverse)

product_category <- tibble(
  food_type = c("Fruits", "Vegetables"),
  category = c("Category A", "Category B")
)

score_schedule_a <- tibble(
  fibre_amount = c(1, 2, 3),
  score = c(3, 6, 9)
)

score_schedule_b <- tibble(
  fibre_amount = c(1, 2, 3),
  score = c(6, 12, 18)
)
```

I think the final function begins like this:

```
score_calculator <- function(fibre, food) {
  category <- product_category %>%
    filter(food_type == food) %>%
    pull(category)
}
```

But I don't know how I can then use `category` to specify which table to look up for the calculation of the score. Steps from here should be that we use `category` to decide which of `score_schedule_a` or `score_schedule_b` to use, and then take the inputted fibre value in the function to pull an associated score.

So some examples of the intended function would be:

`score_calculator(2, "Vegetables")` gives output `12`.
`score_calculator(1, "Vegetables")` gives output `6`.
`score_calculator(1, "Fruits")` gives output `3`.

**How can I pass which table to look up as an argument to my function?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am allowed to do some change to the way data is currently stored, I would store scores in a named list where the name corresponds to the category name.

```
library(dplyr)

lkup_list <- list(`Category A` = score_schedule_a, `Category B` = score_schedule_b)
```

We can then lookup for the selected `category` from this list and return the corresponding `score`.

```
score_calculator <- function(product_category, fibre, food, lkup_list) {
  category <- product_category %>%
    filter(food_type == food) %>%
    pull(category)
  
  lkup_list[[category]] %>%
    filter(fibre_amount == fibre) %>%
    pull(score)
}

score_calculator(product_category, 2, "Vegetables", lkup_list)
#[1] 12
score_calculator(product_category, 1, "Vegetables", lkup_list)
#[1] 6
score_calculator(product_category, 1, "Fruits", lkup_list) 
#[1] 3
```